# Switching to another Screen using onPressed not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying switch to a different screen in Flutter project using onPressed but it is not generating any outcome not sure what is the reason.

Here is the homescreen page:

```
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            const User_Profile();
                                            print("Hello");
                                          },
```

Here is the user profile:

```
class User_Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const User_Profile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  State<User_Profile> createState() => _user_profileState();
}
 
class _user_profileState extends State<User_Profile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("User Profile");
  }
}
```

Question:
How to switch screens using Onpressed? What am I doing wrong noting that the word Hello for debugging is printed everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a function instead of your class like this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>User_profile()));
```

call this:

```
 onPressed: () {
                                       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>User_profile()));
                                      },
```

instead of this:

```
   onPressed: () {
                                        const User_Profile();
                                        print("Hello");
                                      },
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code and use **`Navigator.push`** refer [**navigation**](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

```
  ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => User_Profile(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Text('User Profile'),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

as you know you can't go to a specific page by calling the constructor method in a class. you have 2 ways:

1. use `Navigator.push` like this:

   ```
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => User_Profile(),
          ),
        );
   ```

and you can send the parameters to the next page by sending by constructor parameters like: `User_Profile(name: 'yourName')`.2) you can use `Navigator.pushNamed`. you can define routeName in your main class of the project like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Splash(),
        '/user_profile': (context) => User_Profile(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

as you see you defined a routeName `'/user_profile'` and you can use `Navigator.pushNamed` and if you want to pass parameters to the next page you have to use `arguments` like this:

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
 '/user_profile',
 arguments: {"name" : "yourName"},);
```

and this code is for getting the arguments that you've passed in your User_Profile :

```
var arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
var name = arguments['name'] as String;
```

I recommend you to use the second way to know all your routes of your projects.

Good Luck;)