# use variable value in another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

Im new and my question may be stupid but

in class *Location* i have 2 var :

```
var latitude;
var longitude;
```

then :

```
Location({Key? key, this.latitude , this.longitude}) : super(key: key);
```

and after some works when I print them I get the value

```
print(widget.latitude);
print(widget.longitude);
```

there is no problem here BUT when I want to use these vars in another class like this :

```
var myLat = Location().latitude;
var myLong = Location().longitude;
```

the values are **NULL**

how can get the values the second class too?

Comment: That is beacause you are creating a new instance of each class, you should use a state management solution like Provider, Riverpod, Getx, etc. to access data from different locations in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `Location()` - you create the new instance of this class. It isn't connected to the previous instance you were working on. To make this work you need to type

```
var myLat = location.latitude;
var myLong = location.longitude;
```

WHERE `location` is the SAME object you created previously. So you need to pass it somehow to the place where you're trying to access these fields.

Comment: Or you can not create the object but add the word "static" to the two original variables

Comment: thanks for answer . when I add static then in my methods I can't use these variables . what can I do? it says "create a local variable"

Comment: could you please share your entire class? I can suggest adjustments

Answer (score 1):

as you know you have 2 ways:

1. if you want to navigate from first page to second page you can pass the Location args by the code in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74581206/8388842) to a question. and if you want to read a doc here is the [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).
2. you can use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) as a stateManagement. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588750/8388842) is my answer to using provider. believe me that using stateManagement make your tasks easy .because sometimes you need to use datas from one page to 10 pages later. what you want to do?? do you want to pass datas to every pages?????
   if you didn't understand what i mean, please write in comment down.
   happy coding...
   Moraghebe khodet bash ;)